# Search and replace all in javascript/nodejs

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

My replace all function is as below, it is in commonHelper.js file

```
exports.replaceAll = function (find, replace, str) {
  return str.replace(new RegExp(find, 'g'), replace);
}
```

Then I do following

```
var commonHelper = require('./commonHelper');
var html_body = commonHelper.replaceAll('[[username]]', user_row.username, template_row.message_body);
html_body = commonHelper.replaceAll('[[forgot_pass_link]]', forgot_pass_link, html_body);
```

this is not properly replacing the [[key]] parts here. What should I change to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had to replace special characters. My updated replace all function

```
exports.replaceAll = function (find, replace, str) {
  var find = find.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
  return str.replace(new RegExp(find, 'g'), replace);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use split and join as a replace all.  This removes any issues with regex special characters messing up the find and replace. Example:

```
>> "[boo].blah.[boo].blah".split("[boo]").join("(scare)")

"(scare).blah.(scare).blah"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a replaceAll command in string module.

You might be able to use it like this in util.js:

```
var S=require('string');
exports.replaceAll=function(hay,rplfrom,rplto)
{
    return S(hay).replaceAll(rplfrom,rplto).s;
};
```

Comment: can't find the string module